# 2D Platform shooter Canvas game | Creating the shooting function

Tags: javascript, canvas, game-development

So I'm making this pretty basic game I would say for a school project. I have all the basic controllers working, jumping, navigating left and right, but I'm struggling to find a way to make the character be able to shoot. I would also like to make it so it's like a break between each shoot, like a bolt action. The collision part shouldn't be a problem, so no need for help there.

```
(function() {
 var requestAnimationFrame =
window.requestAnimationFrame ||
window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
})();

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
width = 640,
height = 480,
player = {
x: width / 2,
y: height - 140,
width: 35,
height: 90,
speed: 3,
velX: 0,
velY: 0,
jumping: false,
grounded: false
},
keys = [],
friction = 0.8,
gravity = 0.3;

var hovedkarakterBilde = new Image();
    hovedkarakterBilde.src = "mc1.png";

var boxes = [];

// dimensions
boxes.push({
// venstre vegg
x: 0,
y: 0,
width: 10,
height: height
 });
boxes.push({
// gulv
x: 0,
y: height - 68,
 width: width,
height: 1
});

boxes.push({
x: 120,
y: 250,
width: 80,
height: 80
});
boxes.push({
 x: 170,
 y: 275,
 width: 80,
 height: 80
 });
 boxes.push({
 x: 220,
 y: 325,
 width: 80,
 height: 80
  });
boxes.push({
 x: 270,
 y: 225,
 width: 40,
 height: 40
 });

canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

 function update() {
 // check keys
 if (keys[38]) {
   // up arrow or space
  if (!player.jumping && player.grounded) {
  player.jumping = true;
  player.grounded = false;
  player.velY = -player.speed * 2;
   }
  }
  if (keys[39]) {
  // right arrow
  if (player.velX < player.speed) {
  player.velX++;
   }
  }
 if (keys[37]) {
 // left arrow
 if (player.velX > -player.speed) {
  player.velX--;
  }
 }

  player.velX *= friction;
  player.velY += gravity;

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.beginPath();

  player.grounded = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
  ctx.rect(boxes[i].x, boxes[i].y, boxes[i].width, boxes[i].height);

  var dir = colCheck(player, boxes[i]);

  if (dir === "l" || dir === "r") {
    player.velX = 0;
    player.jumping = false;
  } else if (dir === "b") {
    player.grounded = true;
    player.jumping = false;
 } else if (dir === "t") {
    player.velY *= -1;
 }
 }

 if (player.grounded) {
player.velY = 0;
}

player.x += player.velX;
player.y += player.velY;

ctx.fill();
ctx.drawImage(
hovedkarakterBilde,
player.x,
player.y,
player.width,
player.height
 );

requestAnimationFrame(update);
}



function colCheck(shapeA, shapeB) {
// get the vectors to check against
 var vX = shapeA.x + shapeA.width / 2 - (shapeB.x + shapeB.width / 2),
  vY = shapeA.y + shapeA.height / 2 - (shapeB.y + shapeB.height / 2),
  // add the half widths and half heights of the objects
  hWidths = shapeA.width / 2 + shapeB.width / 2,
  hHeights = shapeA.height / 2 + shapeB.height / 2,
  colDir = null;

 // if the x and y vector are less than the half width or half height, they 
 we must be inside the object, causing a collision
  if (Math.abs(vX) < hWidths && Math.abs(vY) < hHeights) {
 // figures out on which side we are colliding (top, bottom, left, or right)
   var oX = hWidths - Math.abs(vX),
    oY = hHeights - Math.abs(vY);
    if (oX >= oY) {
    if (vY > 0) {
      colDir = "t";
      shapeA.y += oY;
    } else {
      colDir = "b";
      shapeA.y -= oY;
     }
   } else {
     if (vX > 0) {
      colDir = "l";
      shapeA.x += oX;
    } else {
      colDir = "r";
      shapeA.x -= oX;
     }
  }
}
  return colDir;
}

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
keys[e.keyCode] = true;
});

document.body.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
 keys[e.keyCode] = false;
 });

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
update();
});
```

HTML:

```
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" style="background: url('bakgrunn1.png')"></canvas>
 </body>
 <script src="spillv2.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing you have to consider is if the bullet is hit-scan or projectile. Hit-scan means when the bullet is shot, the bullet instantly hits the target. This can be done by  using a ray-cast to check if it hits an object. Projectile based bullets are when the user points in a direction, the bullet actually "moves". This can be implemented by adding an array of "bullets" to the player. So when the player clicks, a bullet object is added the array. This bullet object will be drawn on it's own in the draw loop and will move from the user to the direction it's pointed at.

Adding a delay is simple, you can have a "cooldown" variable that is a counter that lasts for n milliseconds. When the user fires, the counter is set to n and starts to count down to 0. When it reaches 0, you are able to fire again.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could make a `shoot(e)` function, which will be called when user presses (keydown) space for example and then make a new array, lets say `ammo[]`. Then, inside `shoot()` you will do something like:

```
const ammo = [];
let shooting = false;
function shoot(e) {
      e = e || event;
      const key = e.keyCode;
      if(shooting) return; // This will prevent from shooting more bullets while holding space
      // So you'd need to press space for each time you want to shoot.
      if(key == 32) { // Key code 32 is SPACE
         shooting = true;
         // You get the coordinates from your player, from which the bullet will shoot
         ammo.push({
         x: player.x,
         y: player.y + (player.height / 2) 

        // Player.height / 2 is basically setting the ammo at the middle of the character
        });
      }
}
```

And then, I presume you do all the updates in the `update()` function (yea, logically :D), you'll do something like:

```
function update() {
  // Insert it somewhere
  for(let i = 0; i < ammo.length; i++) {
    // The "theBullet" part refers to either your image for the bullet
    ctx.drawImage(theBullet, ammo[i].x, ammo[i].y;
    ammo[i].x++ // Or however fast you'd like it to go.
  }
}
```

Hope its somewhat clear, I am working myself on a spaceshooter type of game, almost finished, so shared some of my code here :) Not implying that its the best, but it does the work :)

Comment: hmm, is it working in your game? It's not working for me even though I followed everything said :/ Thanks anyway though!

Comment: Well, yea it works. Maybe you'd need to change the positioning of the ammo x,y in my example to suit yours. Or if your `update()` is not the main function that does the drawing of the canvas and all of that, then insert the ammo for loop in the function that does that. Also, how are you calling `shoot(e)` function? As I noted above, in my case I'm calling it with a `keydown` event listener attached to the document's body.